# Which is the correct mechanism for the ozonolysis of an alkyne?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

According to *Organic Chemistry* by Jonathan Clayden, Nick Greeves and Stuart Warren (2nd edition), the mechanism for alkene ozonolysis is given as

[image: ozonolysis of alkenes]

In *Advanced Organic  Chemistry, Part B: Reactions and Synthesis*, Francis A. Carey and Richard J. Sundberg (5th edition), the ozonolysis of alkene is given as:

[image: ozonolysis2]

But mechanism of ozonolysis of alkynes is not given.

[image: alkyne ozonolysis]

What is the correct mechanism of the ozonolysis of alkynes?

Comment: See this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25190/preparation-of-oxalic-acid-from-acetylene

Comment: Basically, ozonolysis of alkyne forms different types of compounds, and thus the reaction is too complicated and thus exact mechanism is not completely known. See this: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja010166f

Comment: As to your 2 examples of alkene ozonolysis, if a hydroxylic solvent is present (MeOH), then the zwitterion is trapped as the methoxy hydroperoxide  [R(MeO)C(H)OOH] and it is this species that is reduced. In non-nucleophilic solvent, the ozonide is formed and then reduced.